# Модульный тест файловых операций

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, testng

Впервые задумался над написанием модульного теста для проверки копирования и чтения файлов (Unit написал и использовал заглушки Moq), но не знаю как это сделать. Использую N-Unit. Что необходимо для реализации? В проект с тестами добавить каталог с файлами для физического копирования и destination каталог? 
Код который у меня реализует работу с файлами:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
    {
        var files = new List<string>();
        var directories = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path));
            directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path));
            foreach (string dir in directories)
                files.AddRange(GetFiles(dir));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Debug.WritLine($"Ошибка, файлы отсутсвуют {e.Message}");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Debug.WritLine($"Отказано в доступе {e.Message}");
        }

        return files;
    }


 public void CopyAllFiles(string root, string destinationPath)
    {
        Queue<string> directories = new Queue<string>();

        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        directories.Enqueue(root);

        while (directories.Count > 0)
        {
            string currentDir = directories.Dequeue();
            string[] subDirs = null;

            try
            {
                subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Debug.WritLine($"Отказано в доступе{e.Message}");
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Debug.WritLine($"Папка не найдена{e.Message}");
            }

            string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Debug.WritLine($"Отказано в доступе{e.Message}");
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Debug.WritLine($"Папка не найдена{e.Message}");
            }

            // Бегаем по папкам и подпапкам копируя все файлы
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

                    File.Copy($"{currentDir}/{fi.Name}", $" 
          {destinationPath}/{fi.Name}", true);
                     {fi.CreationTime}";
                    Console.WriteLine($"{currentDir}/{fi.Name} 
          {destinationPath}/{fi.Name}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{fi.Name}: {fi.Length}, 
          {fi.CreationTime}");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Debug.WritLine($"Файл не найден{e.Message}");
                }
            }

            foreach (string str in subDirs)
                directories.Enqueue(str);
        }

     public void СlearFolder(string folderName)
     {
        var info = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);

        foreach (var file in info.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }

        foreach (var directoryInfo in info.GetDirectories())
        {
            СlearFolder(directoryInfo.FullName);
            directoryInfo.Delete();
        }
      }
```

Хотелось бы найти правильное понимание вопроса и посмотреть пример хотя бы на одном методе.

Comment: Что тут тестировать? Классы `Directory, DirectoryInfo` уже протестированы производителем.

Comment: Проверить метод, копирующий дерево каталогов например?

Comment: Проверить на что? Один раз запустили, проверили, что работает и все дела. Зачем это юнит тестами покрывать? Эта логика будет меняться у вас?

Comment: Т.е. ваше мнение, что это бессмысленно? Логика железная. Изменения будут навряд-ли.

Comment: Да, я думаю, смысла нет в этом. Вот если бы вы писали какой то алгоритм работы с нодами дерева и работа с файлами был бы просто одним из вариантов его применения, то тогда да, был бы смысл закрывать файловые операции интерфейсами, писать под них заглушки/имитации, тестить алгоритм с разных сторон и прочее, а так вы просто копируете файлы, это 1 раз настроил и зыбыл.

Comment: Ок! Спасибо за рекомендации!

Comment: Модульные тесты должны быть максимально быстрыми, чтобы разработчики не ленились их запускать почаще. Работа с файлами (а также сетью, БД и т. п.) априори медленная, поэтому модульными тестами не покрывается. Однако, это можно делать в интеграционных тестах, которые запускаются намного реже.

Comment: Код, опирающийся на статические реализации, тестировать невозможно. Чтобы это можно было тестировать, придется избавиться внутри от явных обращений к любым статическим методам. Все `Directory`, `Debug`, `File` и иже с ними придется обернуть в реализации интерфейсов, которые обеспечат инверсию зависимостей при создании экземпляров тестируемых классов. При этом в модульных тестах в конструкторы тестируемого класса будем передавать `псевдореализации`, которые лишь имитируют нужное нам в тестах поведение.